# Why AutoResetEvent and ManualResetEvent does not support name in the constructor?

Tags: multithreading, .net-2.0, synchronization

On .NET Framework 2.0 AutoResetEvent and ManualResetEvent inherit from EventWaitHandle. The EventWaitHandle class has 4 different constructors. 3 of the constructors support giving a name to the event. On the other hand both ManualResetEvent and AutoResetEvent do not support naming and provide a single constructor that receives the initialState. I can simply inherit from EventWaitHandle and write my own implementation of those classes that support all the constructor overloads, but I don't like to re-invent the wheel if I do not have to. My questions are:

- Is there a special problem in naming events?
- Do you have any idea why Microsoft did not support it?
- Do you have a proposal better than inheriting from the EventWaitHandle class and calling the appropriate constructor as in the following example?

```
    public class MyAutoResetEvent: EventWaitHandle  
    {  
        public MyAutoResetEvent(bool initialState)  
            : base(initialState, EventResetMode.AutoReset)  
        {  
        }  
        public MyAutoResetEvent(bool initialState, string name)  
            : base(initialState, EventResetMode.AutoReset, name)  
        {  
        }  
        public MyAutoResetEvent(bool initialState, string name, out bool createdNew)  
            : base(initialState, EventResetMode.AutoReset, name, out createdNew)  
        {  
        }  
        public MyAutoResetEvent(bool initialState, string name, out bool createdNew, EventWaitHandleSecurity eventSecurity)  
            : base(initialState, EventResetMode.AutoReset, string.Empty, out createdNew, eventSecurity)  
        {  
        }  
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make a named manual reset event like so:

```
// Open the event by name.
EventWaitHandle namedMRSE = 
    new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.ManualReset, @"TheName");
```

[Here is the reference](http://codeidol.com/csharp/csharpckbk2/Threading-and-Synchronization/Get-the-Naming-Rights-for-Your-Events/) for the above code. I don't know of the particular reason behind the design, but [there are some notes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ksb7zs2x%28VS.80%29.aspx) on msdn that suggest there is a distinction based on the application domain and the process:

> Event wait handles are useful in many
>   of the same synchronization scenarios
>   as the Monitor  class. Event wait
>   handles are often easier to use than
>   the System.Threading.Monitor.Wait  and
>   System.Threading.Monitor.Pulse(System.Object)
>   methods, and they offer more control
>   over signaling. Named event wait
>   handles can also be used to
>   synchronize activities across
>   application domains and processes,
>   whereas monitors are local to an
>   application domain.

Comment: Your solution is similar to my solution. I call the EventWaitHandle from the derived class constructor and you use it directly.

Comment: @lkaso I thought that it's a little more straight forward than creating a derived class... unfortunately I don't have much to offer as to the reason for the design choices.